# How to read docker env variables into Java code

Tags: java, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize my Java application which tries to connect to a Rabbitmq server. I have passed the Rabbitmq Url via docker env variable and readig the same url using

> System.getenv("RABBITMQ_URL")

, but it came out to be null. Is there anything wrong with the way I am reading the docker env variable ?  Here is my Docker create command :

> docker service create --name xxx --env
>   RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://rabbitmq:xxxx --network msgq --with-registry-auth
>   ${imageName}

Comment: You could check your image with *docker inspect*, the same with your service: *docker service inspect* to check where the variable is blanked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is weird but, restarting the docker container just worked fine for me. Turns out , i have to restart the container when ever I update the network connection using "--network". Thanks

Comment: No, that is not expected. You can connect a network to an existing service even after it was created.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work just fine for me. Please see below:

```
>> cat Dockerfile
FROM java

COPY Test.java /Test.java
RUN javac Test.java
CMD java Test


>> cat Test.java
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] j) {
    System.out.println(System.getenv("RABBITMQ_URL"));
    while (true) {}
  }
}


>> docker build -t testj .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.656kB
Step 1/4 : FROM java
 ---> d23bdf5b1b1b
Step 2/4 : COPY Test.java /Test.java
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2333685c6488
Step 3/4 : RUN javac Test.java
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8d1e98d604b9
Step 4/4 : CMD java Test
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f9625f04966
Successfully built 6f9625f04966
Successfully tagged testj:latest


>> docker service create --name xxx --env RABBITMQ_URL=amqp://rabbitmq:xxxx --detach testj
937rbfctrds0z1mhpk1e7dlja

>> docker service logs xxx                                                                                                                                                      
xxx.1.acv6mqqy38pf@moby    | amqp://rabbitmq:xxxx
>>
```