# Environment variables from Docker are not passed to Spring

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kotlin, environment-variables, spring-bean-dsl

I try to dockerize simple java application.

my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine
COPY build/libs/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
```

In my bean definition file I try to log properties:

```
    beans {
        bean {
            logger.info { "System env: " + env.systemEnvironment }
            // ...
        }
    }
```

but when I call:

```
docker run 123 --env foo=bar
```

It results in `foo` not being visible from java.

However if I run my application from Idea and pass environment variables directly it works as a charm.

Am I missing something? How I can make values passed in `env` available for java?

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596007/how-to-read-docker-env-variables-into-java-code

Comment: try like `docker run -e foo=bar image_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with

```
docker run -env foo=bar your_image:tag
```

And in code,

```
env.getProperty("foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using :

```
docker run 123 --env foo=bar
```

You are actually passing command line arguments to the docker container.

If you want to pass environment variables you should use `-e` (same as --env) option for `docker container run` command :

```
docker run -e foo=bar image_name
```

Refer to setting environment variables in [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file).